# Cast Summon Monster inside a Rope Trick?

Tags: summoning

Can a wizard summon a monster or elemental inside a Rope Trick then exit that space into the prime material plane with that summoned creature and still control it?

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about? Please include a tag to indicate this. There are thousands of RPGs and we can't provide an answer without knowing which one the question is about.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for additional guidance. As PurpleMonkey says, to answer this we need to know what system and edition you are playing. You can [edit] the tag into your post. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: This question is for AD&D and D&D 5e rulesets. Can a Wizard cast "Summon Monster" spell or "Summon Elemental" spell while inside a pocket dimension of the spell "Rope Trick" then exit that pocket dimension with that summoned creature into the prime material plane and still control it?

Comment: What do you mean by "for AD&D and D&D 5e rulesets"? Those are two completely different rulesets, with different versions of the Summon Monster and Rope Trick spells. If you want to know about both rulesets, you should ask about them separately.

Comment: This question is for AD&D. Can a Wizard cast "Summon Monster" spell or "Summon Elemental" spell while inside a pocket dimension of the spell "Rope Trick" then exit that pocket dimension with that summoned creature into the prime material plane and still control it?